# Not able to click a button in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to click a button in my script. The HTML for the button is below. Please have a look and guide me.

I am using Java (Webdriver 4).

```
<td width="55" valign="baseline" align="center">
<input class="Button" width="55" type="button" align="bottom" onclick="changeTab(2)" value=" Next ">
</td>
```

Comment: <td width="55" valign="baseline" align="center">
<input class="Button" width="55" type="button" align="bottom" onclick="changeTab(2)" value=" Next ">
</td>

Comment: I have fixed the formatting issue with your question. Please post the code you are using to click the button.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value=' Next '])")).click();

Comment: I am using this code to click the button. @npinti

Comment: What exactly is the error it throws? Is it under any frames? What exception do you see?

Comment: Any error that you are getting?

Comment: Element not found exception. It is under a frame but I did switch to that frame.

Answer (score 0):

Very common issue with this is the wait or element load time and easiest fix will be to implement some [explicit](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) wait and the possible solution is as follows

```
By css = By.cssSelector("input.Button[value*='Next']");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(css);
 myDynamicElement.click();
```

Comment: I have a dialogue box which opens up. I have switched it its frame as all other functionality is working on that dialogue box. Only this next button is not working. There is a form in the iframe, How can i switch to a form? Could this be the reason why it can't locate? I am now getting the element not visible exception\

Comment: If you switched to a frame you need to switch back to default content and execute commands belong to default window. And, if you have an `iframe` you definitely have to `switchTo()` the frame first

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@value,'Next')]")).click();
```

Comment: I have a dialogue box which opens up. I have switched it its frame as all other functionality is working on that dialogue box. Only this next button is not working. There is a form in the iframe, How can i switch to a form? Could this be the reason why it can't locate? I am now getting the element not visible exception\ –

Comment: The above code clicks on a `input` element that has **Next** in its value attribute

Comment: Paste the code that you have used. Also make sure statements that appear before the above given code are executing without any exception.